# Can Latent Class Analysis be included among the "Machine Learning" methods?

Tags: machine-learning, latent-class

My question is a "semantic" point of view and it's very easy.

Given that Latent Class Analysis (LCA) can be defined as a form of "unsupervised learning", I was wondering whether we can consider LCA among the broad umbrella of "Machine Learning" techniques?

From a broader perspective, this question may be translated to "what qualifies to be a "Machine Learning" method" - but in here I am particularly interested in understanding whether we can consider LCA among the broad ML umbrella, or - instead - if not, and why not.

Comment: By the most generous definition of machine learning, `add trendline` in Excel counts. I guess my point is that the term "machine learning" is rather loose and unhelpful. For what purpose do you want to know if LCA counts as machine learning? Do you, for instance, want to write on a resume or your LinkedIn profile that you do machine learning work?

Comment: @Dave rest assured that I am not intending to pretend I am an expert in ML since I did a LCA once - that's not the point. My question is primarily for curiosity (and to understand the "boundaries" that we should use to define what ML is and what is not), and also to understand which elements of a technique/method are qualifying to belong to the "ML family". My uneducated guess is that LCA could be considered a ML technique as being a form of an unsupervised learning, but would like to hear more expert opinions.

Comment: Hi @user89547235. I've asked myself a similar question in the past. The answer is of course: Yes and No. Yes, because LCA also generates clusters/groups in an unsupervised way, and you'll find that they typically correspond well with clusters generated by recognised unsupervised methods such as k-modes. However, it is also a no because LCA has fairly strict conditional independence assumption required for interpretation, unlike pure distance-based unsupervised methods.  But overall, I agree with @@Dave. It is broadly insignificant.